# Maven build/plugins section inheritance behavior w.r.t to plugin version

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I am trying to understand the inheritance behavior of plugins declared in the build/plugins section of a parent POM.

Specifically, if on POM A i declare a plugin in the build plugins section with a certain version & then on POM B which has POM A as parent i override the same plugin by declaring it again (with some configurations/executions, etc) in its own build plugins section **BUT without specifying the plugin version**.

In this case will POM B inherit the plugin version alone from the one declared in POM A or will it default to the latest version?

Also just to note again i am referring to the build/plugins NOT the pluginManagement section.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration of the plugins in POMs A and B will be merged.

You will inherit the version.

Comment: Cool...that's what i was hoping as alluded in the maven docs but it wasn't clear since it only talks about versions & configurations, etc in the context of pluginManagement.

Comment: Currently that's what i see as the behavior aswell..just wanted to make sure that's the intended behavior..

Comment: one related question then the difference between placing a plugin in the build plugins section vs placing in pluginManagement section is that in the case of the latter the plugins are not inherited, only the version & configurations are WHEN the child pom explicitly declares it in its own build plugins, correct?

Comment: PluginManagement is configuration that is only used if the plugin is also declared in the plugins section. Whether this is in the parent or child is not important.

Comment: I am sorry i did not get the last part regarding "parent or child is not important"...I thought PluginManagement is mainly used with POM inheritance to configure plugins for the children from the parent when they declare them..

Comment: That is true, I just wanted to say that technically for Maven, there is no difference from where these elements come. Maven just merges everything to the effective POM and then runs it.